# Share same wildfly module between multiple war's and jar's

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly, wildfly-8

I want share same wildfly module between multiple war's and jar's .
I have org.json module which I have added as an dependencies in A.war's manifest.mf file and B.jar's manifest file but when I invoke it I get below exception.It tries to load it twice

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/json/JSONObject"
```

Update:
I have deployed A.war and B.jar(my ejb jar) on wildfly server

Comment: Have you setup your common jar **org.json** in $JBOSS_HOME/modules? http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7

Comment: Yes. I have added org.json in wildfly-home/modules/org/json/main  @Franck

Comment: Are you sure you did not package org.json inside your war/ear?

Comment: @Franck There are no jars inside war.

Comment: So where is B.jar if not inside war?

Comment: @Franck I have deployed A.war and B.jar and have configured org.json in both's manifest.mf file

Comment: Has A.war a dependency on B.jar? If yes, what kind remote/local interface? Are parameters passed involved in json transformation?

Comment: if you build with Maven set the scope of the org.json dependency to provided